# adjust space on horizontal axis

Tags: matplotlib

I have created a plot as below using these data.

```
date        mean_step_by_date
26/06/2020  9398.1
27/06/2020  9280.3
28/06/2020  6394.2
29/06/2020  7202.5
30/06/2020  7457.3
20/06/2020  7688.3
21/06/2020  10038
22/06/2020  5889.5
23/06/2020  6960.4
24/06/2020  9915.5
25/06/2020  5796.3
14/06/2020  8699.5
15/06/2020  9733
16/06/2020  8191.5
17/06/2020  12608.5
19/06/2020  7708
18/06/2020  9143.5
08/06/2020  5000
09/06/2020  7251
10/06/2020  3456
11/06/2020  9983
12/06/2020  4523
13/06/2020  10547
```

Horizontal axis is date and it does not show properly. Could you please help? Thank you.

[image]

**Update:** These are codes I used with fig.autofmt_xdate but still not very good

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(s['steps_date'], s['mean_step_by_date'])
fig.autofmt_xdate()
ax.fmt_xdata = mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I have tried with these suggested codes. There was a ValueError that date was not datetime. When I convert it to date and re-run the codes. The graph is very strange.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(s['steps_date'], s['mean_step_by_date'])
locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I also tried codes from another similar post but no graph was shown

```
_ = plt.plot(s['steps_date'], s['mean_step_by_date'])
ax = plt.gca()
plt.axis([0,24,0,50])
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
for label in ax.get_xaxis().get_ticklabels()[::2]:
    label.set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: `fig.autofmt_xdate()`.

Comment: @BigBen: thanks but it is still not good. Is there a way to increase the length of horizontal axis?

Comment: Change the `figsize`.

Comment: Your dates are strings, so matplotlib treats them as "categories" and each "category" gets a tick.  If you want them to be treated as dates, covert to dates using `pd.to_datetime(s['steps_date'])` as in the example below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setting will set it to automatic. Try it!
If you want to customize it further, see this. [Tick Locators](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-locators.html) [Tick formatters](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.0/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html)

update:I updated the code again as both the data and the code were presented to me. If you reorder the data, it becomes a normal graph.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
steps_date mean_step_by_date
26/06/2020 9398.1
27/06/2020 9280.3
28/06/2020 6394.2
29/06/2020 7202.5
30/06/2020 7457.3
20/06/2020 7688.3
21/06/2020 10038
22/06/2020 5889.5
23/06/2020 6960.4
24/06/2020 9915.5
25/06/2020 5796.3
14/06/2020 8699.5
15/06/2020 9733
16/06/2020 8191.5
17/06/2020 12608.5
19/06/2020 7708
18/06/2020 9143.5
08/06/2020 5000
09/06/2020 7251
10/06/2020 3456
11/06/2020 9983
12/06/2020 4523
13/06/2020 10547
'''

s = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data),sep='\s+')
s['steps_date'] = pd.to_datetime(s['steps_date'])
s.sort_values('steps_date',ascending=True, inplace=True)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(s['steps_date'], s['mean_step_by_date'])

locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I have tried but could not see the graph. I am very new to matplotlib. Here is the codes: 
`plt.plot(s['steps_date'], s['mean_step_by_date'])`
`fig, ax = plt.subplots()`
`ax.plot(s['steps_date'], s['mean_step_by_date'])`
`locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator()`
`formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)`
`ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)`
`ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)`
`plt.show() `

Comment: You should add it to the question instead of putting the code on the comment. I think you'll get more answers. And data would be even better.